# Get an FTP folder size using FluentFTP

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, blazor, fluentftp

I want to list out all the folder names and sizes in `/`  path
In my case I have two folders in `/ path

1. `XYZ` (12MB)
2. `ABC` (10MB)

I want to get names and sizes using [FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP) to achieve it with blazor.
I am using [BabyFTP](https://www.pablosoftwaresolutions.com/html/baby_ftp_server.html) as a test FTP server.

what I have done is

```
private void GetFileSize()
{
    using (var conn = new FtpClient("127.0.0.1"))
    {
        conn.Connect();

        foreach (FtpListItem item in conn.GetListing("/"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(item.Size);
        }
        conn.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

But I am getting `Name` correct but I am getting `Size` as `0`.
How to get size of each folder?

Answer (score 1):

(Sub)directory entries in directory listing do not have sizes. Anywhere, just check Windows `dir` command or unix `ls` command.

You have to recursively sum sizes of all contained files. Like this:

```
ulong GetDirectorySize(FtpClient client, string path)
{
    ulong result = 0;
    foreach (var entry in client.GetListing(path))
    {
        if (entry.Type == FtpObjectType.File)
        {
            result += (ulong)entry.Size;
        }
        else if (entry.Type == FtpObjectType.Directory)
        {
            result += GetDirectorySize(client, entry.FullName);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```